# Delphi Get file location

Tags: delphi, path

To determine my exe path, I don't know which code I should use.
Please give me explanation when and why should we use:

**1.**  `ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))`

**2.**  `ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)`

Because both code are rendering the same output.

```
C:\Users\Bianca\Documents\RAD Studio\Projects\Exam1\Win32\Release\
C:\Users\Bianca\Documents\RAD Studio\Projects\Exam1\Win32\Release\
```

Comment: `Application.ExeName` getter internally calls `ParamStr(0)`.

Comment: So, option 2 is always preferred ?

Comment: That's what no one can say. If you don't want to rely on the `Application` object (which needs to include `Forms` unit and requires your application to be the VCL forms application), use `ParamStr(0)`. If you are having a VCL forms application, and you don't mind to include `Forms` unit, you can use a better readable `Application.ExeName`. I prefer `ParamStr(0)`.

Comment: Thank you @TLama It's clear to me now. ;)

Comment: I think ParamStr(0) does not preform well if the application is on a network share.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They both give you the same result, but there are subtle differences.

Application.ExeName references the VCL Application object. The use of this property requires you use the Vcl.Forms unit. Internally this does call the ParamStr(0) function.

Notice that the FireMonkey TApplication class does not have this property (as of XE5). So you cannot call Application.ExeName if you are using FireMonkey. And if you ever migrate a VCL project to FireMonkey you will have to rewrite this.

The ParamStr function OTOH is the System unit and is multiplatform (Win, Mac, iOS and Android, depending OC on the Delphi version you are using). On Windows ParamStr(0) calls the GetModuleFileName function, while on the other platforms it parses the command line returning the first token, which should be full path and name of running executable. *(Thanks to Rob Kennedy for this correction)*

So... I'd suggest you use ParamStr(0) directly.

Comment: Thank you @frazz, very clear explanation. Very appreciate this ;)

Comment: `ParamStr(0)` does not return the "first parameter of the execution command." You're thinking of Unix and C's `argv` array, where the OS and runtime simply forward whatever arbitrary value was passed to `execv`, with the hope that it's the program name. In Delphi, the function treats 0 specially and calls `GetModuleFileName` to directly fetch the name of the EXE file (on Windows, anyway; I don't know its implementation for other platforms).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I've checked the code and updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

They are functionally identical. You would use `ParamStr(0)` if you didn't want the overhead of the `Forms` unit and all it's baggage.